# Cannot link .js files to Joomla. Wrong path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I have been trying for hours to link my scripts to a joomla index.php file. I have a project where code works, but when I reuse that code, it's dead fish.

Here's how I'm trying to link to the external .js files that are in my templates/mytemplate/scripts folder.

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/scripts/contentload.js"></script>
```

I know Joomla has another way of linking external scripts but I'm not sure how to use them: http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

Here's my website that I'm trying to have scripts run on: toggle visibility of "Details" here: http://dgm3740.inkedkeyboard.com/final/index.php/party-packages#

And mobile menu should unfold. Everything worked until loaded to Joomla.

Comment: Maybe try not including php tags in the `src` and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried that. I've also tried adding it through a http:// link, then with /, without /... It just won't hook up.

Comment: Have you tried looking at your error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to link your page to external code in Joomla is to use this block of code, which is found at your link http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

```
<?php
   $document = JFactory::getDocument();
   $document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
?>
```

So in your case, you should try:

```
<?php
   $document = JFactory::getDocument();
   $document->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/scripts/contentload.js');
?>
```

Hope I helped you some :)

Comment: I've tried this path. I assume it goes in the <head></head> tag. Now I get Undefined is not a function error in the logs.

Comment: Are you sure its from either of those lines of code?

Comment: I actually got a line on which the error occured, commented that out, no more error. But codes don't work still... I'm sure I'm doing smth funny... :(

Comment: The nav button toggles open/close but the rest of the menu doesn't show. So I've grabbed all the classes and everything... I'm just stumped as to why only part of code work.